# Calculating the change in pH upon diluting an acid

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, aqueous-solution, ions

> What volume of water is added to $\pu{400 ml}$ of $\ce{HCL}$ solution so that the pH of the solution increases by 1 unit

This is how far i went but the answer says $\pu{1000 ml }$ where am I wrong is there any simplet alternative  to this question?[image]

Comment: You a wrong in applying the Henderson-Hasselbach formula in the first place. It is meant for weak acids, which HCl is not. Then again, the given answer of 1000ml doesn't look right to me either.

Answer (score 1):

As Ivan said in the comments, $\ce{HCl}$ is a strong acid. It dissociates as follows,
$$\ce{HCl -> H+ + Cl-}$$
Now, let us assume the intial pH to be x. Since, $$\mathrm{pH} = \ce{-log[H+]}$$ $\ce{[H+]_i}$ = $\mathrm{10^{-x}}$, where subscript i means initial. Likewise, since final pH= x+1, $\ce{[H+]_f}$ = $\mathrm{10^{-(x+1)}}$ where f means final. Since $\mathrm{V_i = 400 mL}$, since total moles remain the same,
$$\mathrm{M_iV_i = M_fV_f}$$
we get $\mathrm{V_f = 4000 mL}$.
Hence amount of water to be added is $\mathrm{4000-400 = 3600 mL}$.